# Build station with more than one artist

Tags: rdio

[Rdio - web version](http://rdio.com) offers one to listen to a station populated by an artist's songs/albums. It is also possible to have related artists queued in the station.

Is it possible to select specific artists for a station?

<sub>(If it is not, a simple "No it is not possible to do this currently", will suffice)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Rdio was shut down, and acquired by Pandora in 2015.

In Pandora;

> All you have to do is create a station with the artist of your choice
>   then go into station details and press 'add variety' and type in the
>   name of the artist you made the station for. You have to do it a few
>   times but eventually the station will play songs by only that one
>   artist.

([source](https://www.reddit.com/r/Music/comments/3300sp/pandora_life_hack_or_whatever_you_call_some_cool/))